# ASP.NET - ListView and DataPager not working

Tags: asp.net, listview, paging, datapager

I used a DataPager to page through `ListView` data. When `ListView` bound, `DataPager` show many pages below, everything seems to be ok but when i click to another page, After a postback, `ListView` is empty with `EmptyDataTemplate` and of course without pages.

I googled and try one and both workarounds below but they didn't help

```
    protected void DatapPager_OnPreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            listView.DataSource = ((DataSet)ViewState[VIEWSTATE_DATASET]).Tables[0];
            listView.DataBind();
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {               
        }            
        base.OnPreRender(e);
    }

    protected void listView_OnPagePropertiesChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            listView.DataSource = ((DataSet)ViewState[VIEWSTATE_DATASET]).Tables[0];
            listView.DataBind();
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {               
        }            
    }
```

In my case, `ListView`'s data bound in a click event, not on PageLoad.

Anyone can helps me? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Its Simple, Just Get "ID" in "QUERY-STRING" from the Database, Now Set it to the Pager Control Property as `[QueryStringField="ID"]` like:

```
<asp:DataPager ID="DataPagerProducts" runat="server" QueryStringField="ID" PageSize="3">
                            <Fields>
                                <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ShowFirstPageButton="True" ShowNextPageButton="False" />
                                <asp:NumericPagerField />
                                <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ShowLastPageButton="True" ShowPreviousPageButton="False" />
                            </Fields>
                        </asp:DataPager>
```

**Note:** if not woking, then set also `[PagedControlID="ListView_Name"]`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't show how `ViewState[ViewState[VIEWSTATE_DATASET]` gets set.  I am guessing this is getting reset to `null` on postback and you are swallowing the `Exception` that is probably raised on this line trying to cast a null value:

```
 listView.DataSource = ((DataSet)ViewState[VIEWSTATE_DATASET]).Tables[0];
```

Comment: Before binding `dataset` to ListView, i assigned ViewState[VIEWSTATE_DATASET] = dataset. I'm sure that  ViewState[VIEWSTATE_DATASET] != null.